# The concept of a recursive commit in SVN

Tags: svn, recursion, commit, rapidsvn

My office is kinda hooked up on SVN and I'm used to git. However I can do nothing about it, but to adapt.

I noticed there are two different concepts in SVN: *recursive add* and *recursive commit*. What is the difference really? Using RapidSVN I performed *recursive add* on my repo and then in commit dialog I see the following option:

[image]

Note the unselected by default *Recursive* option. Nevermind the absence of any added files and such, it's just for the demonstration purposes. How is this *recursive commit* different from *recursive add*? What's the point?

PS: Why downvoting? I come from git background and there is no such thing as *recursive commit* in Git. Google search turned up nothing. I'm really puzzled at how this thing works.

Comment: You can probably do everything with git-svn.  You can have git locally, but fetch and push from an SVN repo.  Just make sure to read the docs so you don't do anything that will look funny to native SVN clients (like pushing merge commits).

Comment: I already left that job, but thank you for your suggestion.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

svn commit and svn add on the command line both have a flag "--non-recursive" which makes the commit only work on the current directory, and not on directories below. Reading this [1] thread I assume that this checkbox just uses these flags. When the checkbox is unchecked, the --non-recursive flag is used [2].

Having this checkbox default off seems weird to me.

1. http://tigris-scm.10930.n7.nabble.com/Issue-706-New-Cannot-commit-a-deleted-directory-td81162.html
2. http://solitarygeek.com/linux/subversion-and-rapidsvn

Comment: Yeah, having it disabled by default is bothering me too. I had a suspicion, that this had something to do with the `--non-recursive` flag but I wasn't sure and its being off by default contributed to the confusion: it's really wrong to have such a default.

Comment: Also, thank you for your answer. I know this is a tedious novice kind of question and some people are quick to downvote, but I did look for the answer on this and didn't find anything due to misleading naming and this awkward default value. Thanks.